# Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript. I am facing some while declaring Props in typescript as follows:

```
Types of property 'd' are incompatible.
Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

I have one xyzProps which contains some sting type and one is string[] as given below:

```
const d1: string[] = [];

type xyzProps = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: typeof d1;
};
```

When I am trying to use the above propes as follows then it gives an error

```
export type abcPageProps = RouteComponentProps<Partial<xyzProps>> & ReduxProps;
```

Any idea why it gives me this error OR any solution for it.

Comment: Are you sure you can assign const to a type? maybe try to change the const to type or just assign string[] to the d

Comment: Yes, I am assigned const to type and also try string[] to d but it still gives the same error. @yonizilberman

Comment: Can you show us your RouteComponentProps type? 
Does that type contain d: string instead of d: string[] ?

Comment: I don't know How to check it? but I am import it "import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';" with this import.

Comment: maybe try to remove the Partial, I feel sometime that it can be a little intrusive

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
type xyzProps = {
   a: string;
   b: string;
   c: string;
   d: string[];
};

export type abcPageProps = RouteComponentProps<xyzProps> & ReduxProps;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the above thing but it gives the same error. Then I change my declaration of d1 as follows: "let d1:string[] | undefined = undefined" means assign it to undefined and it works for me.